# Multi-Host Network Bandwidth Monitor

Tags: networking, monitoring, network-monitor, network-administration, bandwidth

I do a lot of (mostly WLAN) network-related troubleshooting and administrative tasks.

What I would like is a way to monitor the bandwidth usage of all network hosts in real-time. This way I can quickly locate bottlenecks, identify abusive hosts, and so on.

I could probably whip something up, but if there's something readily available, specifically for this purpose, I'll go with that.

Comment: What OS is used on hosts? I can recommend 10-Strike Bandwidth Monitor for the real time traffic usage monitoring under Windows.

Comment: https://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2495263,00.asp

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking of putting something together yourself you can monitor network usage in python using [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil), details [here](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/), and obviously in python it is simple enough to save &/or share those statistics.

However, for a ready rolled solution based on psutil:

- if your servers are **all** Linux you can use [psdash](https://github.com/Jahaja/psdash) which can either make each server have its own performance summary web page or one master server have the web interface for all of them.
- for mixed OS systems [grr](https://github.com/google/grr), while more complicated to set up, allows you to run [flows](https://github.com/google/grr-doc/blob/master/user_manual.adoc#flows), *which can be used to gather data or perform other tasks on a client,* and [hunts](https://github.com/google/grr-doc/blob/master/user_manual.adoc#hunting) *which  action flows on multiple clients that match a specification*.

Comment: I have never seen you comment an answer that isn't python - do you get commission? ;)

Comment: @ThisIsNotMyRealName - no commission just know a fair bit about Python and since you can do a lot of different things with it and there are a __lot__ of free tools available it is often a good answer. However, my top two answers in terms of votes are both non-python.

Answer (score 1):

I run my kid's traffic on my LAN through a Pi running `ntop` - provides a nice graphical interface of hosts involved, how much bandwidth, etc.

https://www.ntop.org

Comment: Is the pi good for this? I'm a CompSci student, and I was thinking of using one to log all the traffic on my personal LAN with `tcpdump`, to study at my leisure.